# Android: how to move from one fragment to another without the user noticing?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, fragmentmanager

I have two fragments - A and B - both fragments take up the entire screen. When I load my activity I show the user fragment A while in the background I load fragment B (in the fragmentmanager I do replace on fragment A and then on fragment B I do add and hide). Both fragments have relatively similar layouts (or at least it would be fair to say that the layout of A just before the transition is similar to the starting layout of B - views move around) and when I want to move from A to B I do a "show" on B and "hide" on A. It almost works perfectly, but you can still see a short flash of white in between, before B is shown, and it ruins the illusion that both are the same fragment. How can I transition without the user noticing?

A couple of words of explanation as to why there are two fragments and not one - the business logic is separate. Each fragment deals with a different part of the flow and it wouldn't make any sense to combine them.

Things I've tried so far:

• as I said above, I tried adding B in the background and only doing a "show" on it when it's needed - to save any setup time

• I tried overriding the pending transition and putting a fadeout/fadein, but it made no difference

• I tried hiding fragmentA instead of removing it when showing fragmentB, but it made no difference

• I tried overriding pending transition with 0,0 (getting rid of transitions entirely) but it's still the same

Code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.contentBlock, fragmentA, "FRAGMENTA")
            .add(R.id.contentBlock, fragmentB)
            .hide(fragmentB)
            .commit();
```

and later:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .show(fragmentB)
            .remove(fragmentA)
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mMapFragment = new MapFragment();
```

ft.beginTransaction(mMapFragment)
.detach(getactivity)
  .attach(mMapFragment)
  .commit();